# Improving PHP Security of Login

Tags: php, mysql, security, sql-injection

One of my github issues is below. I am having some problems with my security, is there anything that I should or need to improve. Here is an example of code that I use, but throughout the script there are some problems.

```
 <?php
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
include '../config.php';
$pass = substr(sha1($_POST['passwordp'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT), -10);

$conn = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $db_name);

$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `Administrators` WHERE username = '".addslashes($_POST['usernamep'])."' AND password='".$pass."'");

$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `Administrators` WHERE username = '".addslashes($_POST['usernamep'])."' AND password='".$pass."'");

 if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
 $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['usernamep'];
 header('Location: dashboard.php');
 } else {
 header('Location: index.php?alert');

 $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `Administrators` WHERE username = '".addslashes($_POST['usernamep'])."' AND password='".$pass."'");

$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `Administrators` WHERE username = '".addslashes($_POST['usernamep'])."' AND password='".$pass."'");

if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['usernamep'];
    header('Location: dashboard.php');
} else {
    header('Location: index.php?alert');
}
  }
 ?>
```

The link to the whole project is here (https://github.com/poKe-Websites/poKe-Multimedia-editor)

Comment: I removed the [copied answer from here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/117704/49695), as it did not have anything to do with your code. As to the code you posted, it seems to be an [updated version of this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/117272/validating-users-with-mysql). Please re-read the answer there, as you did not really include any of the advise provided (eg regarding prepared statements or weak hashing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already noted in [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/117276/49695), you should really use prepared statements.

You should also not use simple sha1 hashing. Just because you added a `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` parameter to sha1 does not mean that you are using bcrypt. The second argument of sha1 is regarding raw output, not regarding the hashing itself. I provided a link to the correct function in my last answer, it's here: [password_hash](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php).

Apart from that:

- Why do you have duplicate queries? You should remove 3 of them to simplify your code.
- I'm also not sure why you check the validity of the credentials twice. After the first check you already know if the user provided valid username and password, there is no need to check again.
- Your indentation is off, making it really hard to see where what if ends. You can use any IDE to properly format your code.

Comment: I don't understand what you are talking about. Please Clarify. Also downvote?

Comment: @ThomasWilbur I downvoted because your question wasn't asked well (your title did not describe what your code does, it contained my answer to a completely different question, etc), and because this is a follow-up, but you did not include any of the advise given in the original question (apart from fixing the SQL injection, this code seems much worse).

Comment: K Pls help me with this.

Comment: Can you move this to a chat idk how

Comment: **Also I need help with this**

Comment: @ThomasWilbur I understand, but I'm really not sure how I could help you. I already stated what is wrong with your code, and I linked to resources to help you (such as how to use prepared statements or the proper hashing function). I don't really have the time to provide you a 1-on-1 tutorial, or to write the code for you.

Comment: Here we can live code.

Comment: Can you live code using c9.io

Comment: @ThomasWilbur I'm really sorry, but like I said, I don't really have the time to provide you with free coding lessons.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34868/discussion-between-thomas-wilbur-and-tim).

Comment: use chat pls so we can discuss